# Get indices of top x equal elements

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get the indices of all the largest elements who are equal to each other in a sorted list of ints.

So given this list

```
elements:   {1 , 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 13, 13}
index:       0   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12  13  14  15  16  17  18
                                                                  ^   ^   ^
```

I will get this output

```
{16,17,18}
```

So far I've got

```
list.Select((x, i) => new {x, i})
```

To get the indices, but I can't use `OrderBy()` with `First()` or `Single()` because I need all the max elements' indices, not just the very top one.

Is there an elegant way to accomplish this (with LINQ or otherwise)?

Comment: What do you meant by **top elements**? and What you have tried?

Comment: Is it guaranteed to be sorted like the example?

Comment: Why do you think this is a good case for LINQ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thus items are sorted, you only need to get index of first item with max value (that item will have exactly same value as last item), and then create range of indexes starting from this index to the end of list:

```
var items = new List<int> {1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,10,11,11,12,13,13,13};
int startIndex = items.IndexOf(items[items.Count - 1]);
var indexes = Enumerable.Range(startIndex, items.Count - startIndex);
```

Comment: This makes so much more sense than anything I was trying. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The easy/lazy way:

```
        var a = new[] {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 13, 13};
        var b = new List<int>();
        var max = a.Max();
        for (var i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] == max) b.Add(i);
        }
```

Comment: This would calculate `Max` on each iteration of loop.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use LINQ since it is a simple foreach over the collection.

```
//var data = new[] {1, 1, 13, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 13, 13};
var data = new[] {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 13, 13};

var largest = int.MinValue;
var indices = new List<int>();

foreach (var x in data.Select((value, idx) => new {value, idx}))
{
    if (x.value > largest)
    {
        indices.Clear();
        largest = x.value;
    }

    // if unsorted
    //if (x.value == largest) indices.Add(x.idx);

    // if sorted you don't need to check against largest
    indices.Add(x.idx);
}

Console.WriteLine("largest = {0}; indices = {1}", largest, string.Join(", ", indices));
```

Though if you must use LINQ, you can use this option instead of the `foreach`:

```
data.Select((value, idx) => new {value, idx})
    .Aggregate(indices, (idxs, n) =>
    {
        if (n.value > largest)
        {
            idxs.Clear();
            largest = n.value;
        }

        //unsorted
        if (n.value == largest) idxs.Add(n.idx);

        //sorted
        //idxs.Add(n.idx);
        return idxs;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you a result of all the elements that have duplicates with their indices:

```
var result = elements.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
             .Where(g => elements.FindAll(v => v == g.value).Count > 1)
             .GroupBy((a) => a.value).OrderByDescending((g) => g.Key).Take(3);
            //I placed Take(3) as example since you said you need to find
            //elements who are equal to each other,so only those that are
            // not distinct(have duplicates) get into the collection.

            //this will loop through the results and display the value(the item
            //on the list) and its respective index.
            foreach (var item in result.SelectMany(g => g))
            {
                string outcome = item.value + " - " + item.index;
                Console.WriteLine(outcome);
            }
```